# Как остановиться при прокручивании страницы прямо перед элементом

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть элемент на странице, когда я до него скролю, я хочу чтобы я остановился прямо перед ним. Однако, если я начинаю скролить от начала страницы, то к тому моменту когда я дошел до этого элемента, я либо не доскролил немного, или же при следующем прокручивании колесиком мыши он заходит на него. Можно как-то сделать так, чтобы обзор страницы остановился прямо перед ним? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
.block-1{
 height: 2300px;
 width: 100%;
}
.block-2{
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
}
.block-3{
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
}


<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2" id="block-2"></div>
<div class="block-3"></div>


X
--------------------------------------   Когда доскролил,закрыло некотурую часть  
  |                               |      block 2 и если прокручу колесиком вверх, 
  |             block2            |      то, все равно будет не ровно по линии, и 
  |                               |      буден виден block1
  |_______________________________|


✔
--------------------------------------
   _______________________________      Когда доскролил, встало ровно по линии
  |                               |     (нужно так)
  |                               |
  |            block2             |
  |                               |
  |_______________________________|
```

Comment: ??? Имеется в виду, что при скроле и `scrollY` в пределах каких-то значений (range) надо задавать определенное значение?

Comment: @Leonid Не совсем, сейчас добавлю пример

Comment: а можно ваш код увидеть ? На словах то оно понятно, но без вашего решения составлять ответ с нуля такое себе занятие

Answer (score 0):

Стрелочками дергайте скролл только , я не знаю почему плохо работает скролл до элемента, его заметно только если стрелки использовать.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("body");
const targets = container.querySelectorAll(".block");

const options = {
 threshold: 0.5
};

const callback = (entries, observer) => {
 entries.forEach((entry) => {
  const image = entry.target.querySelector("img");
  const isIntersecting = entry.isIntersecting;
  gsap.to(image, 0.5, {
   opacity: isIntersecting ? 1 : 0.5,
   width: isIntersecting ? "100%" : "50%",
   height: isIntersecting ? "100%" : "50%"
  });
  if (isIntersecting)
   entry.target.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
   });
 });
};

observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
targets.forEach((target) => {
 observer.observe(target);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .block {
  height: 150vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .block img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="block">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/115/1000/500.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/116/1000/500.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="block">
  <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/117/1000/500.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Нашел нужные команды, получилось вот так:

```js
let hook = document.getElementById("block-2");

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 390) {

    hook.scrollIntoView();//Вариант 1
    //window.scrollTo(0, 400); Вариант 2
  }
};
```

```css
.block-1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2" id="block-2"></div>
<div class="block-3"></div>
```

Comment: вам не кажется что ваш вопрос не конкретен и не понятен? Нет воспроизводимого примера, нет конкретики, не понятно что вы хотите получить в итоге, если у вас получилось создать то что вам нужно, поделитесь нормальным ответом.

Comment: @MoloF Вы правы, прошу прощения, не с первого раза понял как сделать чтобы можно было запустить.